# Media Query is greyed out and doesn't work when in main CSS file, but works when I put it in a separate CSS file?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have one media query that's exactly like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

    #main {
      width: 60vw;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #title {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 60px 10vw 55px 10vw;
        border-radius: 10px;
  }

    #subtext {
        letter-spacing: .35em;
    }

    #img-div {
        float: right;
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #image {
        width: 10vw;
    }

    #tribute-info {
        width: 75%;
        margin: 10px 25px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: -8px 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    }

}
```

However, its greyed out and doesn't work when I put it in my CSS file, but does work when I put it in a separate CSS file. I made sure its at the very bottom of the page, I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in my head tag on my html doc, and my CSS stylesheet is also linked properly, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

I wouldn't mind just having a second CSS file for media queries, but I have to upload it to codepen.io because its a project I am doing for freecodecamp.org, and I don't know of a way to make a second CSS file/box in codepen.

Comment: Figured it out, I'm just a bit dumb lol. I accidently deleted one of the closing brackets in a previous selector, so everything after that stopped working. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely (by what you describe) that's due to the *order* of the CSS rules: You should always place media queries *after* the regular CSS rules, otherwise they will be overwritten by those, since they apply to all sizes, even if they follow rules that were put in media queries before them.

Comment: I made sure it was at the bottom of the page and placed after all other CSS, assuming that's what you mean right? I can't figure out what else might be wrong :/

Comment: Another reason could be the *specifity*  of the CSS selectors. The selectors in the general rules might be more specific than those in the media queries, which "rules out" the rules with the less specific selectors.